# How to download MIRFLICKR dataset with different resolution size?

Tags: dataset

I need a random image dataset for my project, not long ago I found MIRFLICKR dataset from http://press.liacs.nl/mirflickr/mirdownload.html that suits well with my need. The problem is the maximum resolution on each image is only 500px, anyone know how to download the dataset with bigge resolution?

Comment: Bit late - but why do you actually need a dataset with images larger than 500px?
One suggestion would be deep fashion, which can be downloaded via google drive here 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7EVK8r0v71pQ2FuZ0k0QnhBQnc